# conflict between drop shadow and embossMaskFilter in textView: text invisible

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a textView:

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/textAfter"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="example string"
      android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
      android:textSize="40sp"
      />
```

This textView is later on modified in a series of ways programmatically:

```
imageView_Source = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.source);
textAfter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textAfter);

X_FONT = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "ROCKB.TTF");
//textAfter = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textAfter.setTypeface(X_FONT);
localTextPaint = textAfter.getPaint();
localTextPaint.setTextScaleX(1f);     
localTextPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
localTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
localTextPaint.setSubpixelText(true);
localTextPaint.setMaskFilter(new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },ambientValue, specularValue, blurRadiusValue));
```

and

```
public void onClick(View v) {
      //textAfter.invalidate();
      localTextPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
      textAfter.invalidate();
      localTextPaint.setMaskFilter(new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },ambientValue, specularValue, blurRadiusValue));
      textAfter.invalidate();

}};
```

The onClick is purely for testing purposes. However, if I add the following:

```
 android:shadowColor="#000000"
 android:shadowDx="3.0"
 android:shadowDy="3.0"
 android:shadowRadius="1.0"
```

the text becomes completely invisible. While both the shadow and the mask work when applied individually, neither work when applied in unison (the text straight up does not appear). I am guessing that this has something to do with the mask being applied to the shadow as well, but I'm pretty new to Android coding, so I have really no idea what is causing this or how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing the same thing, and I realized that it was due to hardware acceleration.

To disable hardware acceleration for a particular view do this:

```
<TextView>.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem in my project. I`m able to reproduce this behaviour. 
Tried some things, nothing worked.
I would prefer *.9.png instead.

If you don`t want to use png, this approach looks pretty interesting http://qwerjk.com/magic-text

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a simplified transparent copy of the same object underneath giving it shadow only, while the original one in the foreground is set for emboss.